# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'HierarchyNode<any>'

Tags: typescript, d3.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { select, hierarchy, tree } from "d3";

function ThreeChart({ data }: any) {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);

    const root = hierarchy(data);
    svg
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .join("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("fill", "black").attr("cx", node => node.x) // Property 'x' does not exist 
      .attr("r", 4)
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef} style={{ marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
      <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ThreeChart;
```

I think this is pretty simple and straightforward but because im new to typescript I cant seem to figure this out , what or where should i declare my types , I already try this but it doesnt work :

```
interface DataProps {
  children: DataProps[];
  depth: number;
  height: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  data: Data
}
interface Data {
  name: string;
  children: Data[]
}
```

the pass data look like this :

```
const data = {
  name: "1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "1.1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "1.1.1",
        },
        {
          name: "1.1.2",
        },
        {
          name: "1.1.3",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "1.2",
    },
  ],
};
```

This is the console.log(root) : [image]

Comment: You need to pass the data to a layout generator : `tree(root)`, you're currently only creating a hierarchy but not using any layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the x, y properties. These are augmented after the layout is performed. And you need to use the response from that layout call in the subsequent node manipulations.

Something along these lines:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { select, hierarchy, tree } from 'd3';

interface Data {
    name: string;
    children: Data[];
}

function ThreeChart({ data }: { data: Data }) {
    const svgRef = useRef(null);
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = select(svgRef.current);

        const rootNode = hierarchy<Data>(data);

        // this performs the layout and returns a root node with the x & y props
        const layout = tree<Data>().size([200, 200]);
        const rootPointNode = layout(rootNode);

        svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(rootPointNode.descendants())
            .join('circle')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .attr('cx', (node) => node.x) // Property 'x' does now exist
            .attr('r', 4);
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <div ref={wrapperRef} style={{ marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
            <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ThreeChart;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const data = {
name: "1",
children: [
  {
  name: "1.1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "1.1.1",
    },
    {
      name: "1.1.2",
    },
    {
      name: "1.1.3",
    },
  ],
},
{
  name: "1.2",
},
],
};
```

The data object does not contain the x field, as I see it, it contains only the name and children fields. Therefore, you must set the field x and only then use it